# Keep page from being added to browser history

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile to create a mobile app in combination with phonegap. Now I had this login dialog which I originally set as a dialog (instead of a page). However, I needed to be able to control the functionality of the close button, so I changed it into a page, where i created my own close button.

Now I have a problem of the page being added to the browser history. The problem her is when using this app on Android, hitting back opens/closes the login dialog x number of times, before closing the app... What it really should do is just close the application.

Any idea how I can make this "login dialog" page not be added to the browser history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html):

```
//transition to the "confirm" page with a "pop" transition without tracking it in history           
$.mobile.changePage( "../alerts/confirm.html", {
  transition: "pop",
  reverse: false,
  changeHash: false
});
```

Comment: how did I miss this? Thanks alot!

Comment: This does not omit the entry form being added to $.mobile.urlHistory.stack

Comment: @Rob so how can we omit the entry form being added to $.mobile.urlHistory.stack ?

Comment: @AamirShah The only way I know of would be to retrospectively remove the entry or patch jQM adding an option to allow skipping of this behaviour, although other problems may arise from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use window.location.replace() to navigate to that login page it will omit putting that page into the browser history. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 0):

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history